How to set the limits of a definite integral by substitution?
A worked example in my calculus textbook is to evaluate
$$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\text dx.$$
The book's approach is to use trig identities, but my idea is to use a substitution by letting
$$t=1-\sin2x,$$
but I don't know how to set the limits. I calculated the indefinite integral as follows:
$$x=\frac12\arcsin(1-t),\qquad\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}=-\frac1{2\sqrt{1-(1-t)^2}}.$$
$$\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\text dx&=\int-\frac{\sqrt t}{2\sqrt{1-(1-t)^2}}\text dt\\
&=\int-\frac{\sqrt t}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}}\text dt\\
&=\int-\frac1{2\sqrt{2-t}}\text dt\\
&=\sqrt{2-t}+C.
\end{align*}$$
My question is, in the next step, how to set the limits of integration.
Update
By the way, the answer is $2\sqrt2$.

Evaluate the integral on the regions where $f(x)=1-\sin 2x$ is an injection.

@Andrew: Then in this case, how do you work out the limits?

One way is to substitute back $\sqrt{2-t}= \sqrt{2-(1-\sin2x)}=\sqrt{1+\sin2x}$ and use $x\in[0,\pi]$.

@Soheil: No, you get $0$!

As a hint: It's a periodic function, so you can see $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}dx=\int_{0+\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}dx$$ now it has maximum on the interval at $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ so you can divide it into two equal integral like below $$\int_{0+\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}}\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}dx=2\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}dx$$ and now apply $t$ substitution $$[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}] \\ f(x)=1-\sin 2x \ \text{increasing}\\t=1-\sin 2x \mapsto [0,2] $$

Thanks! This was what I had in mind, which was not expressed as precisely as you did. On my rough paper, I wrote $\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\text dx=4\int_0^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\text dx$, which was wrong.

I was stuck with the misconception that I should start with $0$.

As @CPofPhysics pointed out in her/his answer, you need to invert the upper and lower limits, which you did not mention.

This is quite a long answer...as you already got a great answer. You might peek at it for some real reason why you should adopt that method of periods.
The main problem arises in the range of the arcsine.
First, let's do it the simple trigonometric identity way:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\text dx=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\sin x\cos x}\text dx=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{(\cos x-\sin x)^2}\text dx=\int_0^\pi |\cos x-\sin x| \text dx$$
Now, for $x\in [0,\pi]$, $(\cos x-\sin x)$ would take positive values (including zero) in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and negative values in $(\frac{\pi}{4},\pi]$.
So, we have to split the integral for this two intervals as the mod function would be negative in the second interval. Then,
$$\int_0^\pi |\cos x-\sin x|\text dx=\int_0^{\pi/4} (\cos x-\sin x)\text dx+\int_{\pi/4}^\pi -(\cos x-\sin x)\text dx$$
Which would give:
$$I=[\sin x+\cos x]_0^{\pi/4}-[\sin x+\cos x]_{\pi/4}^\pi=2\sqrt2.$$

So, we have got our answer now, let's begin with the substitution method.
We let:
$$t=1-\sin 2x$$
Since, $x\in [0,\pi]$ so $t\in[0,2]$.
Now,
$$t=1-\sin 2x \implies x=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin (1-t)\tag{1}$$
Here's the catch: The range of $x$ as implied by the above relation is $[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$ but in the integral the original limit requires it to be $[0,\pi]$.
Why this happened?
See, the "principle" range of arcsine is $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. So, from $eq(1)$, we get that:
$$\frac{-\pi}{2}≤2x≤\frac{\pi}{2} \implies \frac{-\pi}{4}≤x≤\frac{\pi}{4} \tag{2}$$
Then, so as to cover the whole range of $x$ i.e. $[0,\pi]$, we have to choose the range of arcsine ourselves and split the integral into the corresponding intervals of range of $x$ which comes form each of the part. Let's decode it:
We have to choose those ranges of arcsine which makes it a function as well as help us extend our range of $x$.
For example, consider the range $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$.We can cover the domain $(-1,1)$ using this range as the sine takes all the values from $1$ to $-1$ exactly one time in this interval.This shows that it makes the arcsine a function.
Now, consider the $eq(1)$ with this range. Then, $x$ would follow:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}≤2x≤\frac{3\pi}{2}\implies \frac{\pi}{4}≤x≤\frac{3\pi}{4}\tag{3}$$
Clearly, we have extended the range of $x$ till $3\pi/4$. But we are still less than $\pi$.
Consider another range of arcsine to be $[\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}]$.This again ensures that arsine if a function as before.
Now, the range of $x$ for this range of arcsine would be:
$$\frac{3\pi}{4}≤x≤\frac{5\pi}{4}\tag{4}$$
So, we have covered the whole range which we needed for $x$ (actually beyond it).
Now, let's turn to the calculations:
$$   
x=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(1-t)\implies \frac{\text dx}{\text dt} = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}} &\quad\text{if}\quad x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\cup[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}]\\
       \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}} &\quad\text{if}\quad x\in [\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}] \\
     \end{cases}\tag{5}
$$
This is because:[Graphs of arcsine with ranges $[\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}]$(top), $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$(middle) and $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$(bottom)]

Clearly, the slope of the middle one in negative of other two hence expressed as derivative in $eq(5).$
Now, the splitting:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\text dx=\int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\text dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\text dx+\int_{3\pi/4}^\pi \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\text dx$$
By substitution and using $eq(5)$, we get:
$$I=\int_1^0-\frac{\sqrt t}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}}\text dt+\int_0^2\frac{\sqrt t}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}}\text dt+\int_2^1(-)\frac{\sqrt t}{2\sqrt{2t-t^2}}\text dt=[\sqrt{2-t}]_1^0+[\sqrt{2-t}]_2^0+[\sqrt{2-t}]_2^1=2\sqrt2.$$
The limits of $t$ are set accordingly as the interval of $x$ using the $eq(1)$.

I like the first approach $(+1)$.

I see your point: when the gradient is negative, we have to invert the limits. I thought of this approach but forgot this point and wrongly thought that the limits would simply cancel out. Thanks for adding another tool to my repertoire!

@ZiruiWang Exactly! I am happy that you got the point

@Soheil Yeah,the first approach is easy but the second one is more enlightening!

Let's assume that $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}dx$$
Here I don't think that one should change the limits.
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}dx$
Now $1$ can be written as $\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)$
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)-\sin(2x)}dx$
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)}dx$
Clearly this is of the form of $\sqrt{(a-b)^{2}}$
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^{2}}dx$
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|dx$
Now you have to consider $4$ intervals. Those are $(0,\frac{\pi}{4}),(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}),(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{4}),(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi)$
$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|dx+\int_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\pi}|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|dx$
Now take into consideration some angles like $30^{°},60^{°},135^{°},150^{°}$ and check whether $(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$ is positive or negative.
If positive then while removing modulus $[\sin(x)-\cos(x)]$ will come and if negative then while removing modulus $[\cos(x)-\sin(x)]$ will come
Finally integrate accordingly. It will be done.

Good approach, but I believe it is similar to the beginning of @CP of Physics's answer.

Yes. Exactly @Soheil

no need to consider 4 intervals

Why not @SineoftheTime ? In general the magnitude changes after each $45°$.

analyze the sign of $\sin x -\cos x$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}dx=\frac12\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin x}dx\overset{x\to \frac\pi2-x}=\frac12\int^{\frac\pi2}_{-\frac{3\pi}2}\sqrt{1-\cos x}dx=\frac12\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\sqrt{1-\cos x}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1-\cos x}dx=\sqrt2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\frac x2)dx=2\sqrt2.$$

As you have already received answers on how to solve the integral by splitting it or by exploiting symmetry to change the bounds, I will share a solution which keeps the bounds same.
Noting that $|x|=x\,\text{sgn}(x)$, we can write the indefinite integral as
$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\,\mathrm dx&=\text{sgn}(\cos x-\sin x)\int\cos x-\sin x\,\mathrm dx\\&=(\sin x+\cos x)\text{sgn}(\cos x-\sin x)+C\end{align}$$
Now, if we want to directly apply the FTC to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\,\mathrm dx$, we need to ensure its anti-derivative function is continuous in $[0,2\pi]$. You can see why by 'wrongly considering this "anti-derivative"(though it's not actually an anti-derivative, but I'm taking just to explain why anti-derivatives must be continuous) of $2x$:
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}x^2, x<1\\ x^2-1, x\ge 1\end{cases}$$
If we apply the FTC blindly on $F(x)$ to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^12x\mathrm dx$, we get $0$ which is absurd. Hence,

To apply FTC on the anti-derivative of a function to compute its definite integral in a particular interval, the anti-derivative must be continuous in that interval.

The function $f(x)=(\sin x+\cos x)\text{sgn}(\cos x-\sin x)$ is continuous $\forall x\in[0,2\pi]-\left\{\frac\pi4\right\}$. So, we need to redefine $f(x)$ so that it is continuous at $x=\frac\pi4$ if we wish to plug in $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$ directly to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\,\mathrm dx$:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}(\sin x+\cos x)\text{sgn}(\cos x-\sin x)\forall x<\frac\pi4\\ 2\sqrt2+(\sin x+\cos x)\text{sgn}(\cos x-\sin x)\forall x\ge\frac\pi4\end{cases}$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\,\mathrm dx=g(2\pi)-g(0)$$
$$\therefore\boxed{\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\sin2x}\,\mathrm dx=2\sqrt2}$$

How is $F(x)$ an antiderivative? Antiderivatives are continuous; are you using a different convention?

@SineoftheTime sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant if we consider that as an anti-derivative, it'd be wrong. That's what I was trying to explain.

I get your point, but I don't think it fully addresses the problem (another issue with $F(x) $ is that it's not differentiable at $x=1$).  As pointed out by CP, the range is the problem

Aside from the upper bound being $2\pi$ and not $\pi$, I'm not convinced your main argument is right. FTC Part 2 states, "Let $f$ be a real-valued function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and $F$ a continuous function on $[a,b]$ which is an antiderivative of $f$ in $(a,b)$: $F'(x) = f(x)$. If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$." The proof of this theorem assumes $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ by the Mean Value Theorem. The antiderivative $g$ that you have is piecewise continuous and not differentiable at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

$$\int\sqrt{1-\sin2x}dx=\int\frac{|\cos2x|}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx=\operatorname{sgn}(\cos2x)\sqrt{1+\sin2x}+C$$
So, the continuous anti-derivative on $[0,\pi]$ is
$$F(x)\begin{cases}\sqrt{1+\sin2x}&\text{if $x\in[0,\frac\pi4]$}\\2\sqrt2+\operatorname{sgn}(\cos2x)\sqrt{1+\sin2x}&\text{if $x\in(\frac\pi4,\pi]$}\end{cases}$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1-\sin2x}dx=F(\pi)-F(0)=2\sqrt2.$$
